# How to import UI assets or layouts from Sketch 3 directly to Android Studio?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, sketch-3

I have developed the UI and flows for an android app on **Sketch 3**. Now, I am developing that app. So, is there any way to directly exports the layouts or even individual `assets` to **Android Studio**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There many plugins for **sketch** .

**e.g**   You have to install this plugin for **sketch 3** see  [link](https://github.com/geertwille/sketch-export-assets)

**Installation**

The actual location of your Sketch plugins directory will vary. To open it just click on the Reveal Plugins Folder under the Plugins menu in sketch.

Run following command after going to the sketch plugins folder:

```
git clone git@github.com:GeertWille/sketch-export-assets.git sketch-export-assets.sketchplugin
```

OR

Create a new directory called **sketch-export-assets.sketchplugin** and place the content of this repository in it.

Once you have checked out the plugin repository into the relevant directory, you'll find the plugin functions under the Plugins menu in Sketch.

Comment: Installation manner changed... Just informing you to take a look in the README if you want to use my plugin :)